# Implementing SOAP message handler on server side

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I need to write a message handler. I am following this tutorial https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-server-side/.

I created my handler and used it my service implementation class like

```
@Component(value = "AccountValidationsoapImpl")
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.abc.validation.api.IAccountValidationService")
@HandlerChain(file = "./handler/handler.xml")
public class AccountValidationSOAPImpl implements IAccountValidationService
```

My handler.xml is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <javaee:handler-chains 
       xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <javaee:handler-chain>
      <javaee:handler>
        <javaee:handler-class>com.abc.validation.api.handler.WSHandler</javaee:handler-class>
      </javaee:handler>
    </javaee:handler-chain>
  </javaee:handler-chains>
```

I run my application and send a SOAP request but I never see my handler getting invoked.

Both my handler.xml and WSHandler are present in com.abc.validation.api.handler
while the webservice class is present in com.abc.validation.api package. What am I missing?

My WSHandler

```
    public class WSHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>{

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {

      System.out.println("Server : handleMessage()......");

      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {

      System.out.println("Server : handleFault()......");

      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
      System.out.println("Server : close()......");
    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
      System.out.println("Server : getHeaders()......");
      return null;
    }

    private void generateSOAPErrMessage(SOAPMessage msg, String reason) {
      try {
        SOAPBody soapBody = msg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody();
        SOAPFault soapFault = soapBody.addFault();
        soapFault.setFaultString(reason);
        throw new SOAPFaultException(soapFault);
      }
      catch(SOAPException e) { }
    }

  }
```

Comment: what makes you think, it is not invoked ?? could you share same log/details ?

Comment: Ya. I put log message to get printed, inside handleMessage() method when it gets invoked which never gets printed. Also in debug mode, the flow never goes there. Something like this .                                           
  @Override
   public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {

 System.out.println("Server : handleMessage()......");

Comment: could you share `WSHandler` class ?

Comment: added in the question

Comment: I looked at this https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/05/logging-jax-ws-soap-messages-in-spring.html and created a DefaultHandlerResolver and registered it as a bean in my jaxwsconfig.xml. In debug mode, I see DefaultHandlerResolver being called and registering WSHandler. But, upon sending SOAP request, WSHandler still not getting invoked.